# Creating an exact copy of a pdf file

Tags: asp.net, itext

How can I create an exact copy of a pdf file found on my server using itextsharp and save it under a different name. I will basically end up with 2 files with the same content but different names. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Just use [`File.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy.aspx). No need for `itextsharp`.

```
File.Copy(pathToPdf, pathWithNewName);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need itextsharp for this? Why not just [create a copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy.aspx) of the file?